# Updating Userprofile

Tags: php, sql, session

I have a session.php and a welcome.php page. There I have my userprofile.

I am trying to update the email field.

When I change my email address and press the update button I get the echo Update Successful, but it does not update. I think it still has the old value from the session and I need to clear it.

session.php:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
session_start();

$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];


$ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select * from clients where email = '$user_check'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$_SESSION['email']= $row['email'];
$_SESSION['username']= $row['username'];
$_SESSION['firstname']= $row['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname']= $row['lastname'];
$_SESSION['birthdate']= $row['birthdate'];
$_SESSION['street']= $row['street'];
$_SESSION['streetnr']= $row['streetnr'];
$_SESSION['city']= $row['city'];
$_SESSION['plzz']= $row['plzz'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
  header("

location:http://localhost:81/Left_over_youth_website/pages/login.php");
    }
?>
```

welcome.php:

```
    <?php
     include("../php/session.php");
    ?>
 <div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="imagepageback">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="profilimage"></div>
                                <hr class="verticalline">    
                                      <?php                                 
                                        $sql = "UPDATE clients SET emaill = $_SESSION WHERE email = $user_check";
                                        $update = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                                        if($update){
                                            echo("update sucessful");
                                            $_SESSION["emaill"] = $email_session;
                                        }
                                        ?>                 
                                    <form class="form" action="" method="post">
                                    <input id="usernamee" class="usernamee" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" readonly>
                                    <input id="emaill" class="emaill" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" readonly>
                                    <input id="firstnamee" class="firstnamee" type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?>" readonly>
                                    <input id="lastnamee" class="lastnamee" type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['lastname']; ?>" readonly>
                                    <input id="birthdatee" class="birthdatee" type="text" name="birthdate" value="<?php echo $SESSION['birthdate']; ?>" readonly>
                                    <div>
                                        <input id="streett" class="streett" type="text" name="street" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['street']; ?>" readonly>
                                        <input id="nrr" class="nrr" type="text" name="streetnr" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['streetnr']; ?>" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input id="cityy" class="cityy" type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['city']; ?>" readonly>
                                        <input id="plzz" class="plzz" type="text" name="plzz" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['plzz']; ?>" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#" class="editprofilelink" id="editprofilelink"  onclick="editable(); showbt()"; >Edit Profile</a>
                                    <a href="changepd.html" class="editpasswordlink">Change Password</a>
                                    <input hidden id="btupdate" type="submit" name="btupdate" value="Update">   
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where is `$email_session` defined? Where is `$_SESSION` set?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards look at my session.php file. $email_session = $row['email'];

Comment: You’ve spelt `emaill` wrong. And your `$email = "SELECT * From Clients";...` line is super confusing, you’re trying to set an update to equal a select query?

Answer (score 0):

echo 'update successful' on update query.
Try the following.

in welcome.php:

```
<?php     
    if(isset($_POST['btupdate'])){ 
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];             
        $sql = "UPDATE clients SET emaill = '$email' WHERE email = '$email_session'";

        $update = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if($update)
{
     echo("update successful");
}

?>
```

Comment: does not output update succesful and does not update either. But at least it gives no errors

Comment: echo $sql and and run the query in db

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Left_over_youth_website\pages\welcome.php on line 194 I always get this error thats something is wrong at the end of the page with this statment

Comment: hedge and echo($sql); wont change something either the page just reloads

Answer (score 0):

You have a fatal error over this code:

```
<?php                                 
$email = "SELECT * From Clients";
$sql = "UPDATE clients". "SET emaill = $email". "WHERE email = $email_session";
if(isset($_POST['btupdate'])){
    $update = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    echo("update sucessful");
}
?>
```

this part ("UPDATE clients". "SET emaill = $email". "WHERE email = $email_session") returns this string "UPDATE clientsSET emaill = example@example.comWHERE email = example2@example.com

try this instead:

```
$sql="UPDATE clients SET emaill = $email WHERE email = $email_session"
```

be careful when using concatinate it won't add any space for you.

And you are not changing the $_SESSION["email"] after changing it. you must add $_SESSION["email"] = $email;

```
 <?php                                 
$email = "SELECT * From Clients";
$sql = "UPDATE clients SET emaill = $email WHERE email = $email_session";
$update = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if($update){
    echo("update sucessful");
}
?>
```

Comment: and where do i Need to add $SESSION["email"] = $email;. in the session.php?. And with that Statement you gave me there it would not really update when i press the update button right.

Comment: if($update){
    echo("update sucessful");
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
}

you need to do this to change the email inside the session variable you are not obliged to do it since you can simply make the person logout the moment he/she changes the email address.

Comment: still only reloads the page

Comment: It should refresh the page but the data will be changed in your session beside in your session.php change all variables to be $_SESSION["example"]=$row["example"] since the session is a global variable already you don't need to do it like this you are just getting yourself work harder like this use $_SESSION["email"] instead of $email_session for example of change $email_session whenever you change the email.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I did what you said, but im still not sure how to fix it. I updated the code in my question can you take a look at it? The Thing is in future it should not just update the input field email. It should update all fields...

Comment: in welcome.php $sql="UPDATE clients SET emaill = $_SESSION WHERE email = $user_check" is not going to work put $_SESSION['email'] instead of $_SESSION and it will just update the email in your database and the fields. if you want to update all fields try to put a query for each one if they are in separate tables and allow the user to change them as he likes. and change the $_SESSION['example'] for each one when it is changed although this is not important since you can simply make the person logout when he change the email or password which will cause him to login again leading to change them

Comment: beside every thing in session.php is fine but you better put `if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){...}` before signing the $_SESSION variables it makes it safer. this is my email address if you wanna talk to me for more since I might forget to look here some times. "abbass.sharara.3@gmail.com"